# ComboBox not refreshing item using DataBindingSource

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, combobox

I am using a ComboBox with DataBinding source. I am setting DataSource property of binding source and then item are reflected in databinding source.

Item also reflecting in ComboBox.Item.Count when I see in watch, but on UI screen updated item not refreshing.

```
this.bsInventoryDepartment.DataSource = mLstDepartments;
```

Comment: with databinding changing the whole collection cut the link with the original. if it's the same collection the `mLstDepartments` you need, You must not have set it to a new object. you need to do something like `mLstDepartments.RemoveAll();` and then add all one b one so you call the `mLstDepartments.Add(Object obj)`. these example are if `mLstDepartments` is a List<> but it's just to explain that you need to remove and add and not Overwrite the collection

Comment: Does your items refresh after closing and restarting your application? Normally this is the case with databinding. However when I had this problem I used Table Adapters, fill and refresh. This way I could see the reflection without closing the application.